# Javascript module pattern scope with this

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I was developing using module pattern, and  was wondering why I can't acces to the module scope using this. Maybe I'm wrong with the understanding of the revealing module pattern.

Here is the code I use :

```
var BLOG = window.BLOG || {};

BLOG.Module = (function(){

    var 
        _this = this,
        _hasLoaded = false;


    function init(){
        console.log(_this); // Logs the Window object

    }


    function _privateMethod(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'lazyload/lazyload.html',
            success : function( data ){
                // _hasLoaded = true; // I want to access the variable in my module, How do I refer to it? 
            }

        });
    }


    return {
        init : init
    };

})();
```

Comment: What is it you want to refer to with `this`? Can you give an example?

Comment: I've added what I wanted to do, in the ajax success, I want to access the _hasLoaded variable and set it to true.

Comment: @ arlg: You just use `_hasLoaded = true;` `_privateMethod` and your ajax success handlers are both closures over that variable. I've updated my answer with details and what may be a useful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is determined by how a function is called. If it's called directly, not through an object property (as your outer scoping function is), within that call `this` will be the global object in loose mode (`undefined` in strict mode). On browsers, that's the window object.

You wouldn't normally use `this` to try to refer to things within that outermost scoping function (for this reason).

If something did this:

```
BLOG.Module.init();
```

...then within the call to `init`, `this` (not `_this`) would refer to `Module` and you could refer to other properties on the object you create at the end of your outermost scoping function (there aren't any others currently, just `init`).

---

Re your edit:

```
var 
    _this = this,
    _hasLoaded = false;

// ...

function _privateMethod(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'lazyload/lazyload.html',
        success : function( data ){
            // _hasLoaded = true; // I want to access the variable in my module, How do I refer to it? 
        }

    });
}
```

Just uncomment that line:

```
_hasLoaded = true;
```

This is because both `_privateMethod` and any ajax success handlers created as a result of calling `_privateMethod` are *closures* over the variables defined within your outermost scoping function. So you just refer to them directly.

If this use of the word "closure" is unfamiliar, don't worry, [*closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

---

Side note: This is an odd construct:

```
var BLOG = window.BLOG || {};
```

...as it mixes code requiring that it be at global scope with code that doesn't require that it be at global scope. It's entirely functional, it's just a bit odd. I'd probably go one way or the other:

```
// Requires that it's at global scope (and yes, this does work)
var BLOG = BLOG || {};
```

or

```
// Creates a global whether it's at global scope or not
window.BLOG = window.BLOG || {};
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, When I console.log(this) on init, I get the init function, but not the Module

Comment: @arlg: Again, it depends on how you call it. If you call `BLOG.Module.init()`, within `init`, `this` will be `BLOG.Module` (the object you're returning from your scoping function).

Comment: @arlg: It would really help if you answered the question I asked you almost as soon as you posted the question (see the comment under the question).

Comment: Thanks, I am ashamed with that question, I think I over complicated the problem or messed up with my variables names. Anyway, thanks for your time and your links, I will read this.

Comment: @arlg: :-) No worries, glad that helped! Best,